# How to write a soql query will give you accounts that have any contacts and get the contacts

Tags: soql, query, account, contact

How can I write a `SOQL` query will give me `Account` records that have any related `Contact` records and *also retrieve those* `Contact` *records*?

I am using the below query, but it doesn't retrieve the contacts

```
Select Id, Name From Account Where Id IN (Select AccountId From Contact)
```

Answer (score 7):

I recommend you read [A Deeper look at SOQL and Relationship Queries on Force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com). Everyone who works with `Apex` probably should.

In addition to the `Left Inner Join` you have in your `WHERE` clause, you need a `Left Outer Join` in your `SELECT` clause.

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Name FROM Contacts) // Left Outer Join
FROM Account WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact) // Left Inner Join
```

Comment: +1 for recommending A Deeper look at SOQL and Relationship Queries on Force.com!